# Bureau of Labor Statistics Series ID Formats Question

Tags: labor

https://www.bls.gov/help/hlpforma.htm

I know about the above site, and it's very helpful in terms of querying the BLS dataset. However, it does not seem to contain information about how to query for macro level employment characteristics like Civilian Labor Force, Unemployment Rate, etc.

For example, say I wanted the size of the unadjusted (seasonally) Civilian Labor Force for white men with less than a high school diploma (25 years & older). The series ID for this query would be: LNU01092181. But I'm not really sure how this series ID was structured and how to then intelligently query for other related fields (e.g. for women, different educational attainment, for different races, etc.)

Can someone help? Am I being dumb and missing something glaringly obvious in the Series ID format FAQ page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.bls.gov/cps/#data

This website had sort of what I was looking for.

Under "More Tools" there is information concerning "LN series id list", "LE series id list", etc. While it doesn't break down the "logic" of how the series ids are created, at least it's a pretty comprehensive breakdown of all the series id and what they are.